# Multiple Page Printing Text File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, printing

Im trying to loop a textfile to be printed base on the given record count from the dataset
but it just overwrite a whole page and can't continue and create a 2nd page. Can anybody help me with my code. Thanks

```
//Calling the Print Document Event and the TextFile 

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
                string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText
                (Application.StartupPath+"\\tempnotice_planet.txt");
                string printPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\tempnotice_planet.txt";
                streamToPrint = new StreamReader(printPath);
                printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10);
                printDocument1.Print();
                streamToPrint.Close();
            }


//Printing Code
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {


        float yPos = 0f;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
        string line = null;
        int i = 0;



        for (i = 0; i <= records.Tables["Files"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // Calculate the number of lines per page.

    float linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

    // Print each line of the file. 
            while ((count < linesPerPage && ((line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null)))
            {

                yPos = topMargin + count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);
                ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
                count++; 
            }

    //after a set of textfile printed..Return to the begining of the textfile to print it again for next batch
    //Continuos Printing
            if (streamToPrint.EndOfStream)
            {
                streamToPrint.DiscardBufferedData();
                streamToPrint.BaseStream.Seek(2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                ev.HasMorePages = true;
            }

              if (count > linesPerPage)
              {
                  ev.HasMorePages = true;
                  count = 0;
              }
              else
              {
                  ev.HasMorePages = false;
              }

           }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

printDocument1_PrintPage should print one page only, then exit. It should set ev.HasMorePages to true except after printing the last page, when it should be false.

You can leave the file position alone between calls. Just get rid of the outer loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= records.Tables["Files"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
```

Comment: This is how to do it. Each time printDocument1_PrintPage is called, it starts on a new page. Your function always returns with ev.hasmorepages = false, after printing the entire file, so it is only called once and prints the entire file on a single page.